# Fire Danger Forecast index- classification - USGS

Tags: arcmap, classification, reclassify, land-classification

I recently downloaded a raster image called Fire Danger Forecast index from **[USGS - Fire Danger Forecast](https://firedanger.cr.usgs.gov/apps/staticmaps)**, and I wanted to get the probability of fire for a set of points I have in another layer, but the thing is that the symbology table does not comes with the data.

I find this very strange because without the table, it is very difficult to classify the whole range of color pixels (0-255) to get the fire probability (0%-100%) for each one.

[image]

There is a table available at the website but is a PNG (image) so I can't know where to break exactly.

[image]

Does anyone has any workaround about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the [tiff file](https://edcintl.cr.usgs.gov/downloads/sciweb1/shared/firedanger/download-tool/source_rasters//emodis_lfp_data_20200610_20200610.zip) for Large Fire Probability which has 256 pixel values. It appears that from 0-100 are the actual probability for fires. You can see this in the table of contents when you open it in ArcMap.

I think you can probably omit any values between 101 and 250 as they're outside the USA. Values greater than 251 probably have such a low probability of large fires that you could probably assume a probability of zero.

You could use the [Con](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/con-.htm) tool to extract values less than or equal to 100 to extract the values with actual probabilities. You'll need the Spatial Analyst extension for that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately the Fire Potential Index has a color ramp that goes from 0-green to 247-red. Maybe there is some way to group the similar colors together? It's really a shame that they don't provide the .lyr file. D:

Comment: The version I opened had the correct values.

Comment: yes, but you opened Large Fire Probability. I'm trying to classify the other one that is called Fire Potential Index, and has a different color ramp.